# code for finding the state,country,city from the IP Adress in php

Tags: php, ip-address, ip-geolocation

Sir,
   I developing a site. In which i get the IP addresses of the users from where they are entered. Now i want to find the State,City and country from where they are entering.That means i want to find the state, country, city from the IP address of the user. the code i need in php. can you help me to do that

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at using the [Geo IP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php) module? For example, the [`geoip_region_by_name()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-region-by-name.php) function:

> The **geoip_region_by_name()**
>   function will return the country and
>   region corresponding to a hostname or
>   an IP address.
>
> This function is currently only
>   available to users who have bought a
>   commercial GeoIP Region Edition. A
>   warning will be issued if the proper
>   database cannot be located.
>
> The names of the different keys of the
>   returning associative array are as
>   follows:
>
> - "country_code" -- Two letter country code (see
>     [geoip_country_code_by_name()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-country-code-by-name.php))
> - "region" -- The region code (ex: CA for California)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.hostip.info/ is another option if geoip isn't available.

Answer (score -1):

You can actually get the full country name from http://www.iptolatlng.com, What you have to do is build a simple php code.
Here is a fiddle for the code http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/mih-iqn

The site returns a jason from php we are decoding that to get the country name.

```
country
countryFullName
state
stateFullName
city
zip
lat
lng
areacode
```

these are the results you can get back from the site.